# Iframe login resulting in Page Expired

Tags: wordpress, laravel-5, iframe

So i have created two website one is for front page (WordPress) and the other one is for Member Area (Laravel) because of various reason .. i have to make the login button in front page to become popup iframe

[image: iframe popup]

So when i click login it will redirect me to member area (i'm using `target="_parent"`).
But when i tried to login it will return with this

[image: page expired]

Does anyone have idea how do i fix this?

PS : the website url is like this WordPress (testing.com), Laravel (testing.com/members)

Comment: Note : i able to fix this by changing the session setting in Laravel from "Lax" to "None", but i don't know if this safe or not